# save changes when iterating over multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, group-by

First, Thanks to the community for the help.

The problem that I can't solved is the following:

I create a function to group data. After this, I create a 'for' loop to read through all the DataFrames and group data in each of them, but I don't know how to save the changes since when calling dataframes again it are unchanged.

For example:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_0' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'col_1' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],'col_2' : [5, 4, 8, 9, 4],'col_3' : [6, 8, 3, 7, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_0' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'col_1' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'D'],'col_2' : [4, 9, 6, 7, 4],'col_3' : [4, 5, 6, 8, 4]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'col_0' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'col_1' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'D'],'col_2' : [9, 5, 5, 4, 5],'col_3' : [7, 2, 9, 3, 8]})
df_4 = pd.DataFrame({'col_0' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'col_1' : ['A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E'],'col_2' : [2, 4, 4, 1, 6],'col_3' : [1, 9, 2, 6, 5]})
df_5 = pd.DataFrame({'col_0' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'col_1' : ['A', 'E', 'A', 'E', 'D'],'col_2' : [4, 7, 5, 0, 1],'col_3' : [2, 6, 5, 4, 2]})
df_6 = pd.DataFrame({'col_0' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'col_1' : ['A', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'B'],'col_2' : [7, 6, 8, 6, 7],'col_3' : [5, 6, 8, 5, 7]})
df_7 = pd.DataFrame({'col_0' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'col_1' : ['A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B'],'col_2' : [3, 4, 8, 8, 9],'col_3' : [6, 3, 9, 6, 1]})
```

```
lista = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5, df_6, df_7]
```

```
def group (df):
    df = df.groupby(['col_0','col_1']).sum()
    return df
for i in lista:
    group(i)
```

Once the 'for' is done, when is calling any 'df_' again, the changes have not been saved:

```
df_2
```

Results:

```
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3
 0   A      A      4     4
 1   A      A      9     5
 2   A      B      6     6
 3   D      E      7     8
 4   E      D      4     4
```

Expected results:

```
df_2.groupby(['col_0','col_1']).sum()
```

```
col_0   col_1       
  A       A      13      9
          B      6       6
  D       E      7       8
  E       D      4       4
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: the programming language is python

Comment: Then I'd suggest to add the `python` Tag in order to make your question visible to the interested audience

Comment: You are right,  I forgot that part, Thanks for your help Stefan!!

Answer (score 0):

This could help you out, I think;

```
def group (df):
    df = df.groupby(['col_0','col_1']).sum()
    return df

grouped_dfs = {}
c = 1
for i in lista:
    grouped_dfs['df_%s'%c] = group(i)
    c += 1
```

Then, you could get the results for the first df with

```
grouped_dfs['df_1']
```

and so on.